# Difference between logistic map and logistic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

I'm doing a research project on Chaotic Encryption using the logistic map(?). I'm still in my early stages, and my professor made the following question:

> What's the difference between the logistic map and the logistic equation?

The thing is, I'd say: the map is the 'function' described by the 'equation' $x_{n+1} = \lambda  x_n(1-x_n)$.

Would this be an accurate answer? I've never asked myself this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **logistic equation** usually refers to the differential equation
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = r x \left( 1 - \frac{x}{K} \right)
,
$$
i.e., a **continuous-time dynamical system** which gives you a function $x(t)$, $t \in \mathbf{R}$, given an initial value $x(0)$.

The **logistic map** is the function on the right-hand side,
$$
f(x) = r x \left( 1 - \frac{x}{K} \right)
,
$$
and usually when talking about the logistic map one is interested in the **discrete-time dynamical system** obtained by **iteration** of this map,
$$
x_{n+1} = f(x_n)
,
$$
which gives you a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbf{N}}$ given an initial value $x_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clear explanation.

Comment: You're welcome!